# Create menu from multi dimensional infinite parent child tree

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Anyone?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if you need any additional info.

I am attempting to turn a multi dimensional array to a multiple nested html navigation menu.  I have the jist of it from another answer on SO: [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685825/php-loop-through-multidimensional-array-and-establish-parent-child-relationship).

What I am trying to figure out is how to preserve the top level parent link (and any subsequent child page links) in the url for the next child array.  I tried passing in the link to the function when it calls itself to build the array, but that only preserved the most recent parent link.

Example:

Home 
About
-Info
--Sub Page

becomes:

home
about
about/info
about/info/subpage

Here is a sample array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12
        [parent] => 11
        [name] => Sub Page
        [link] => sub_page
        [target] => _self
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 14
        [parent] => 12
        [name] => Test
        [link] => test_test
        [target] => _self
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 9
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Home
        [link] => home
        [target] => _self
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 11
        [parent] => 10
        [name] => Info
        [link] => info
        [target] => _self
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 13
        [parent] => 10
        [name] => Test
        [link] => test
        [target] => _self
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 10
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => About
        [link] => about
        [target] => _self
    )
```

)

And here is the code I am using:

```
function create_menu_array($arr, $parent = 0){
    $pages = array();
    foreach($arr as $page){
        if($page->parent == $parent){               
            $page->sub = isset($page->sub) ? $page->sub : $this->create_menu_array($arr, $page->id);
            $pages[] = $page;
        }
    }
    return $pages;
}

function create_menu_html($nav){
    $html = '';
    foreach($nav as $page){
        $html .= '<ul><li>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . base_url().$page->link . '" target="'.$page->target.'">' . $page->name . '</a>';
        $html .= $this->create_menu_html($page->sub);
        $html .= '</li></ul>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with recursive function:

example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pmw-7i3

```
<?php

function array_process_for_ids($items) {
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $new_array[$item['id']] = $item;
    }
    return $new_array;
}

function menu($items) {
    function menu_recursive($parent_item) {
        global $items;
        unset($items[$parent_item['id']]);
        echo '<div style="padding-left: 15px;">';
        echo '- '.$parent_item['name'];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item['parent'] == $parent_item['id']) {
                menu_recursive($item);
            }
        }
        echo  '</div>';
    }
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['parent'] == 0) menu_recursive($item);
    }
}

$items = array(
    array(
        'id' => 10,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Top Page 1',
        'link' => 'top_page_1',
        'target' => '_self'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 12,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Top Page 2',
        'link' => 'top_page_2',
        'target' => '_self'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 25,
        'parent' => 10,
        'name' => 'Sub Page 1 of top page 1',
        'link' => 'sub_page_1_of_top_page_1',
        'target' => '_self'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 26,
        'parent' => 12,
        'name' => 'Sub Page 1 of top page 2',
        'link' => 'sub_page_1_of_top_page_2',
        'target' => '_self'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 28,
        'parent' => 26,
        'name' => 'Sub Page of sub page 1 of top page 2',
        'link' => 'sub_page_of_sub_page_1_of_top_page_2',
        'target' => '_self'
    )
);

$items = array_process_for_ids($items);

menu($items);

?>
```

Comment: Your answer does not do as asked in the question, if I am mistaken please let me know.