# generate breadcrumb from given array. PHP

Tags: php, recursion

[based on this array mentioned here :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685825/php-loop-through-multidimensional-array-and-establish-parent-child-relationship)

I am trying to generate breadcrumb like this

```
main>link1>link2>link3
main>link1>link2
main>link1
```

this is i am going

```
function GenerateBreadcrumbHTML($nav) {
$html = '';
foreach ($nav as $page) {
    $html .= '';
    $html .= '<a href="' . $page['link'] . '">' . $page['name'] . '</a> >';
    $html .= GenerateBreadcrumbHTML($page['sub']);
    $html .= '</br>'; 
}
return $html;
```

}

but i am getting output as:

```
main cat 1 >sub main of 1 >
sub main of 1 >

main cat 2 >sub main of 2 >
sub main of 2 >

main cat 3 >sub main of 3 >
sub main of 3 >

main cat 4 >sub main of 4 >sub cat of 11 >
sub main of 4 >
```

please explain me the logic so that i can get the desired result.